# how to get list of field names by select its node type in drupal?

Tags: nodes

I got the all node type list in a variable using [get_node_type_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7) and now am passing this variable to [field_info_instances](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) as:

```
array_keys(field_info_instances("node", $op_keys));
```

ps: *$op_keys is the variable to get node types.*
But this is giving me list of **node_type** "keys" and I want **field** "keys".

Either tell:

> (1)how to pass list of all node types as a $bundle_name in
>   field_info_instances() ?

or

> (2) when selecting any of the **node_type** (*as an option of select
>   list*) from select list, it's corresponding **field's name** will get
>   rendered. I mean to say for example: node_type = "Article" and its
>   field names  = *"body", "title", "image"*. when "**article**" got
>   clicked from select list, *"body", "title", "image"* should get
>   rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [field_read_fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_read_fields/7) you should be able to request `keys` as a parameter in argument 1. And then for the conditions in argument 2 limit the fields returned by the inquiry by supplying `entity` and `bundle` keys to limit how many fields you get back. You may get back the fields used in the bundle -- but it should include the keys value.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of field names for each content type,, stored in a variable "list", given an array of bundle names, you could do:

`$list = array();
foreach($bundle_names as $bundle){
   $list[$bundle] = array_keys(field_info_instances('node', $bundle));
}`

Hope that helps.

Comment: it is giving me only only first name of field on every select. not working

Comment: Not sure I understand. What does "first name of field" mean? It gives you a list of machine names for each field, keyed by the bundle name for each content type

Comment: @SuagndhKhanna This is the correct solution to (1) in the original post. You can't pass multiple bundle names to `field_info_instances`. You can only pass 1. Therefore you loop through your bundles like Ollie showed you how to.